# How can two airlines have the same IATA code?

Tags: airlines

I have found a peculiarity in the IATA codes used to identify airlines.

Both **BHAir** (Bulgaria) and **Heli France** (France) have the IATA code `8H`.

Any ideas why this is and doesn't this cause problems?

Comment: It gets weirder - [according to this site](http://www.airlinecodes.co.uk/airllistres.asp?airliata=8&airlicao=) 8H is the IATA code for Fly Lappeenranta.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's possible for two airlines to share the same code, under some circumstances. They're usually in different regions of the world.  [There are only a limited number of two-letter combinations](https://helpdesk.flightstats.com/entries/20069653-Is-it-true-that-2-different-airlines-can-have-the-same-IATA-code-).

In addition, [from Wiki:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_codes)

> After an airline is delisted, IATA can make the code available for
>   reuse after six months and can issue "controlled duplicates".
>   Controlled duplicates are issued to regional airlines whose
>   destinations are not likely to overlap, so that the same code is
>   shared by two airlines. The controlled duplicate is denoted here, and
>   in IATA literature, with an asterisk (*).

My working theory is that possibly Heli France has shutdown? I can't find recent references to it...

To back up this theory, it's worth noting that [Fly Lappeeenranta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_Lappeenranta) also had the same IATA code, but stopped flying in 2010.

so in conclusion, it's entirely possible for airlines to re-use past IATA codes, and also potentially possible for duplicate ones in non-overlapping regions of the world, given the limited set of 2-letter codes ((26+10)^2) = 1296 airlines.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer, and it is not a theory as you said, it is a fact, once the airlines is not IATA member any more, IATA can use the same code for other airlines.

Comment: its actually less, because O and 0 or 1 and I are not both used to avoid confusion. Thats also the reason why no airline uses rows/seats I but J instead